# Azure API Management - set up Authorization using non-standard provider

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an API which I need to set up authentication against, which is not set up in a standard OAuth2-compliant workflow. Essentially, I need to make a `GET` request against `https://{APIUrl}/Login`, and pass `userName` and `password` as request headers. The request returns, in the request body, two properties - `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`, which I then use against subsequent requests.

Is there any way to use Authorizations for this? If not, is the recommended approach to instead use the `send-request` policy to make a pre-request against the `Login` endpoint to obtain the `AccessToken`, and then use that as part of the primary API call?

Answer (score 0):

Please Note that, to get refresh token from the API, you need to add `offline_access` permission in the scope and `offline_access` only works for **Authorization code flow** as Grant type. It will not give you token for **Client credentials flow** as it has **Application** type permissions only

**Azure AD**-
[image]

I have tried to get the tokens (access and refresh) using Postman below-

[image]
[image]

Please include **scope** as offline_access api//{application id}/.default
[image]

Add the Callback URL in Azure AD as shown below-
[image]

When you will click on **Get New Access Token**, one new window will open where you need to login with your credentials as below-
[image]

After successful authentication, you will get both **access and refresh** token
[image]

[image]